# Passing data in when using $compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list where when you click on an item it throws a popover with detail info on that particular item. I have it setup with a directive to compile a new popover directive on the fly and remove/destroy it on close.

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/m9d7s5oo/4/).

```
//JS    
angular.module('compileExample', [])
      .controller('CompileController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

          $scope.things = [{name:'One'},{name:'Two'},{name:'Three'}];

      }])
    .directive('primaryDir', ['$compile', function($compile) {
        return {
            scope: {},
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.on('click', function() {
                    /* NOTE: The string template in template would get large and is nasty. */
                    var data = JSON.parse(attrs.primaryDirData),
                        template = $compile('<div class="panel panel-cover js-bind">Data from '+data.name+'<button ng-click="remove()">Remove</button></div>')(scope);
                    angular.element('.container').append(template);

                    scope.remove = function() {
                        angular.element('.js-bind').remove();
                    };
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

// HTML
<div ng-app="compileExample">
  <h2 class="inject">Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="CompileController" class="container">
      <div class="well" ng-repeat="thing in things" primary-dir primary-dir-data="{{thing}}">
          {{thing.name}}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**

The string template in my directive's link function is nasty and its going to get larger. So I decided to break out the template rendering into it's own directive so I can use the directive's API for template loading. Working [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/m9d7s5oo/5/). But now its not passing the proper data through and I'm getting the old null/ [object Object]. If anyone has any recommendations to build data-driven directives on the fly I would love to identify some best practices. I'm not married to $compile, it just seems like the most performant option.

```
// JS    
angular.module('compileExample', [])
      .controller('CompileController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

          $scope.things = [{name:'One'},{name:'Two'},{name:'Three'}];

      }])
    .directive('template', function() {
        return {
            replace: true,
            template: '<div class="panel panel-cover js-bind">Data from  <strong>{{foo}}</strong> <button ng-click="remove()">Remove</button></div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.foo = !attrs.data ? 'bar' : attrs.data;
          }
        };
    })
    .directive('primaryDir', ['$compile', function($compile) {
        return {
            scope: {},
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var data = JSON.parse(attrs.primaryDirData);
                element.on('click', function() {
                    var template = $compile('<div template data="'+data+'"></div>')(scope);
                    scope.$apply(function (){
                        angular.element('.container').append(template);
                    });
                });

                scope.remove = function() {
                        angular.element('.js-bind').remove();
                    };
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have forked & rewrited your fiddle a little, so now it looks like http://jsfiddle.net/749yq8ez/8/

Use of `JSON.parse` & separete template directive for this case is odd as you may see.

The right deсision for a case of large template - is to move it into `script` tag or into separate file and use of `$templateCache` service